# Using set_value + another value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth, setvalue

I've got a login form and I'm using Tank Auth for form validation, etc. For the form, I'm not using labels; instead I am populating the value field to tell users what to input (e.g., Email Address in the "email" field). But Tank Auth presets the value with a set_value function:

```
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login'),
);
```

Is there any way to keep the set_value function, but also enter a value that can be used in place of a label? Or is there some other way to get users to see the instructional text without getting rid of the set_value function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to set a second argument for set_value().

For example, you could write this:

```
$login = array(
'name'  => 'login',
'id'    => 'login',
'value' => set_value('login', 'You\'re username'),
);
```

To set the preset value (if nothing else has been entered) to *You're username*

Comment: Thank you! It's little things like this that drive me nuts. Appreciate your help.